# QGIS on Ubuntu hanging at 'save file' dialogue

Tags: qgis, ubuntu

Whenever I encounter a 'save file' dialogue in QGIS (saving processing results, duplicating a layer, 'save project as'), QGIS hangs entirely for around 60 seconds.

I am using QGIS 3.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 (though the problem has persisted through several QGIS versions and through Ubuntu 16.04 -> 17.10 -> 18.04).

I have inspected the output of /var/log/syslog when the problem occurs. It tends to spit out a few lines like this:

```
May  3 10:03:15 [MACHINE NAME] qgis.bin[26657]: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
May  3 10:03:15 [MACHINE NAME] dbus-daemon[950]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.300' (uid=1000 pid=26657 comm="/usr/bin/qgis.bin " label="unconfined")
May  3 10:03:15 [MACHINE NAME] anacron[25909]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2018-05-03
May  3 10:03:15 [MACHINE NAME] systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
May  3 10:03:15 [MACHINE NAME] anacron[25909]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
May  3 10:03:15 [MACHINE NAME] systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
May  3 10:03:15 [MACHINE NAME] org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1805]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x5e057f1 (Save Layer)
May  3 10:03:15 [MACHINE NAME] dbus-daemon[950]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
May  3 10:03:15 [MACHINE NAME] systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
```

I'm not sure how relevant they are. These lines occur immediately when I open the file save dialogue (preceding the 60 second freeze) and no new messages are spat out when QGIS starts responding again.

I have searched quite extensively for people with similar problems, to no avail. I'm not expecting a fix, but I seek any advice on how to further diagnose the problem. What else should I be monitoring?

Some extra info: the freeze isn't *quite* immediate. There is about a second where the file dialogue still responds, and if I can click 'OK' or 'Save' before that, then all is well. Not sure what this indicates.

Following suggestion from bugmenot123, I ran

```
strace -e file -p $(pidof qgis.bin) | grep -v '/etc/localtime'
```

I am having a hard time understanding the output, which is here: https://pastebin.com/V9Xm7rFW. The freeze occurs at 12:52:30 and lasts until 12:53:57.

I also ran `strace -c` to see what QGIS is spending its time doing:

```
 % time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
 ------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 23.11    0.101156           1     86037     54292 stat
 12.75    0.055794          11      5259           poll
 12.24    0.053552           9      5970       707 futex
 6.53    0.028583          10      3004           writev
 6.36    0.027817           1     21698           read
 5.98    0.026168           9      2836           getdents
 5.86    0.025652           2     11115      4179 openat
 5.66    0.024754          20      1212           select
 4.00    0.017521           1     12063           pread64
 3.81    0.016690        2782         6           wait4
 2.78    0.012169           1     14772        13 lseek
 1.98    0.008670         377        23           clone
 1.77    0.007763           1      9660           fstat
 1.55    0.006789           1      6768           close
 1.34    0.005885           1      4435      3630 recvmsg
 0.96    0.004222           1      3532        25 lstat
 0.86    0.003760           1      4003           write
 0.61    0.002666           2      1543           mmap
 0.38    0.001656           2       763           mprotect
 0.26    0.001133           1      1229           fcntl
 0.19    0.000835           0      2404      2391 ioctl
 0.16    0.000707           1       584       382 access
 0.13    0.000570           2       365           brk
 0.13    0.000555           1       417         3 readlink
 0.12    0.000538           2       319           munmap
 0.08    0.000349          10        34           fdatasync
 0.05    0.000204           1       397           getpid
 0.04    0.000181           0       444       438 mkdir
 0.04    0.000158           0       439           getrandom
 0.03    0.000138           1       272           fstatfs
 0.03    0.000121           9        14           rename
 0.02    0.000096           1        90           rt_sigaction
 0.02    0.000084           1       113           madvise
 0.02    0.000069           2        30           unlink
 0.02    0.000068           8         9           ppoll
 0.01    0.000063           2        37         7 recvfrom
 0.01    0.000055           0       114           fadvise64
 0.01    0.000045           6         7           inotify_add_watch
 0.01    0.000043           1        48           eventfd2
 0.01    0.000033           4         8           dup2
 0.01    0.000025           1        18           geteuid
 0.01    0.000023           2        11         3 connect
 0.00    0.000021          11         2           execve
 0.00    0.000021           2        13           fchmod
 0.00    0.000021           1        16           clock_gettime
 0.00    0.000018           1        21           pwrite64
 0.00    0.000018           1        14           socket
 0.00    0.000017           1        12           sendmsg
 0.00    0.000016           1        30           uname
 0.00    0.000016           1        20           getcwd
 0.00    0.000015           1        15           flock
 0.00    0.000015           8         2           arch_prctl
 0.00    0.000014           1        10           shmat
 0.00    0.000013           1        12           shmget
 0.00    0.000013           1        10           getuid
 0.00    0.000011           1         9           getegid
 0.00    0.000010           2         6         5 statfs
 0.00    0.000009           3         3           rt_sigreturn
 0.00    0.000009           1        18           sendto
 0.00    0.000009           3         3           getgid
 0.00    0.000008           8         1           getppid
 0.00    0.000006           2         4           inotify_init1
 0.00    0.000005           1         5           rmdir
 0.00    0.000005           0        18           pipe2
 0.00    0.000004           1         3           prlimit64
 0.00    0.000003           0        13           shmctl
 0.00    0.000003           1         5           getsockname
 0.00    0.000003           3         1           sched_getaffinity
 0.00    0.000003           3         1           waitid
 0.00    0.000001           0         4           rt_sigprocmask
 0.00    0.000001           1         1           shutdown
 0.00    0.000001           1         2           bind
 0.00    0.000001           0         4         1 getpeername
 0.00    0.000001           1         1           getsockopt
 0.00    0.000001           1         2           sysinfo
 0.00    0.000001           0         3           getresuid
 0.00    0.000001           0         3           getresgid
 0.00    0.000000           0         5           mremap
 0.00    0.000000           0         3           dup
 0.00    0.000000           0         3           kill
 0.00    0.000000           0         3         1 semget
 0.00    0.000000           0         6           semop
 0.00    0.000000           0         3           semctl
 0.00    0.000000           0         5           shmdt
 0.00    0.000000           0         1           chmod
 0.00    0.000000           0         1           setuid
 0.00    0.000000           0         1           sigaltstack
 0.00    0.000000           0         1           mlock
 0.00    0.000000           0         1           munlock
 0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_tid_address
 0.00    0.000000           0         1           clock_getres
 0.00    0.000000           0         5           tgkill
 0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_robust_list
 ------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 100.00    0.437674                202430     66077 total
```

It seems to be spending a lot of time doing poll, stat and futex, but i'm not sure if this is normal. I get the feeling the hang is caused by blocking of some sort.

Comment: Do you have (or ever had) network drives attached? What happens if you disable your network adapter(s)?

Comment: I do have network drives, but the issue persists even if I unmount them all and switch off my network adaptor.

Comment: Launch QGIS and then right before you do what makes it hang, enter `strace -e file -p $(pidof qgis) | grep -v '/etc/localtime'` in a root shell. That will show you which files qgis tries to access and might give you hints.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've updated the question with some strace output.

Comment: I think http://hub.qgis.org/ is the better place to solve this, with assistance from the developers.